# Get the groups of the device in Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get the group membership of the device in AAD.

It is possible to get the groups, select one, get members and find a device there in one call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/xxx/members/yyy
```

I can get to the same device as by calling

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/registeredDevices/yyy
```

But I haven’t found anything for a reversed approach for the device. It is simple to find the group membership of a user

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf
```

but this apparently doesn’t seem to be possible for the device. Neither in v1.0, nor in beta.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you are looking for something that will tell you what groups a device is a member of like:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices/memberOf`

We don't have anything like that today.

**However** we do have an alternative, that might work for you, and it provides transitive closure too (which memberOf does not). See: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/directoryobject_getmembergroups

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices/{deviceId}/getMemberGroups
{
"securityEnabledOnly":false
}
```

The response will contain a list of group ids for which the device is a member.  To get the group details, you will have to make another call.  You *could* use the `getByIds` action for this - see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/directoryobject_getbyids.  If you want to do this in one call, you could take a look at using batching: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching.

Hope this helps,